# Text file encoding properly as utf-8 in Scite editor but fails to encode to uft-8 in ruby

Tags: ruby, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a text file which if viewed in the Scite editor with the encoding set to `utf-8`, displays all text correctly, including capital letters with an accute accent (i.e. Á).

However, if I write a ruby script and use `mystring.encode("utf-8")` it will give me this error on capital letters that carry an acute accent (i.e. Á):

`encode': "\x81" to UTF-8 in conversion from Windows-1252 to UTF-8 (Encoding::UndefinedConversionError)`

Is this expected behaviour? How can I encode the whole text to `utf-8` using ruby, knowing that otherwise it does get successfully encoded in the Scite editor?

Code:

```
ine_file = File.open("../../_data/ine_spain_demographics.csv", 'r')

ine_towns_population_hash = Hash.new

ine_file.each do|line|
    values = line.split(";")
    town_name = values[3]
    population = values[4]

    begin
        ine_towns_population_hash[town_name.encode("utf-8")] = population
    rescue
        puts "problematic string: " + town_name
    end

end
```

Comment: I can provide a link to the text file tonight

Comment: Your `town_name.encode("utf-8")` call is a little suspicious since you say that the file is already UTF-8. What does `ine_file.external_encoding` have to say?

Comment: @mu_is_to_short `ine_file.external_encoding >> Windows-1252` I want to encode to UTF-8 which works fine in Scite apparently

Comment: @muistooshort comment above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say that `ine_file.external_encoding` says `Windows-1252` so the file is being opened as a Windows-1252 encoded file. Then you say `town_name.encode("utf-8")` in an attempt to encoded a string as UTF-8 and Ruby complains. But the file is actually UTF-8; reading UTF-8 bytes as Windows-1252 and then trying to recode those bytes as UTF-8 isn't going to work.

You need to open the file in UTF-8 mode:

```
File.open("../../_data/ine_spain_demographics.csv", 'r:UTF-8')
```

and stop trying to change the encoding of `town_name`, just use `town_name` as-is.

Comment: "But the file is actually UTF-8", why? How do you know the file is UTF-8, are you talking about `ine_spain_demographics.csv` file?

Comment: `ine_spain_demographics.csv` is the only file we're talking about and you say that "the Scite editor with the encoding set to utf-8, displays all text correctly" so presumably the file's bytes represent UTF-8 encoded text. But `external_encoding` says that the file is being treated as 1252 encoded text when you open it so everything goes haywire.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like it's misinterpreting the encoding of `ine_spain_demographics.csv`.

Looking at the doc's for [encode](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/String.html#method-i-encode) and [open](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.4/IO.html#method-c-new) you have two options:

1. Use `replace` in encode to tell Ruby what character to use `town_name.encode("utf-8", replace: '')`.
2. Identify the correct file encoding and specify it: `File.open("../../_data/ine_spain_demographics.csv", 'r:ISO-8859-1')`

Comment: I guess @Travis, the problem is that Scite's encoding functions is just more advanced than ruby's, because Scite can encode neatly into utf-8 while ruby has a problem with upper case acute-accent caracters. -